# what is the predictor value in prediction interval

Tags: statistics

I am trying to figure out something about the prediction interval, I am trying to figure out if I have the "predictor" correct, some equation marks it as $x_0$, some as $x_{n+1}$, some as $x_H$, some as $x_{Predictor}$.

Do I put the first value of the data set or last value of the dataset in it?

[image: Prediction interval equation]

Answer (score 0):

$x^{\,}_{\text{predictor}}$ should be the particular value of the independent variable you have use to get the prediction (presumably $\hat{y}_0$ in your expression?) of the dependent variable

Comment: http://www.propharmagroup.com/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/equation_bunch_pg_10.jpg?itok=l8rhuqyt   In this example, the x values are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and they want to predict the 5th value, so they put in 5? So if i want to predict the latest value i put in 10?